# how to access to file in another domain by ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get, dns

How to access to file in another domain by ajax
(I don't want use any php files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com) has a nice plug-in that extends the jQuery ajax function to use YQL. You can find it here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you can not access a file in another domain unless you are dealing with modern age browser that supports [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) or you are just requesting a webservice with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP)

You could remove your browser security setting and allow the cross domain calls. Just hand the keys and monsy over to the hackers now. :)

Answer (score 0):

ive done a trick with get values like putting them into 1 string like
ape=22;bird=23;tiger=44

than converted that string to base64 (to eliminate character problems)
YXBlPTIyO2JpcmQ9MjM7dGlnZXI9NDQ=

than put that string into a domain like
http://example.com/YXBlPTIyO2JpcmQ9MjM7dGlnZXI9NDQ=/

on that domain you can convert it back to your original values